# Nullpointerexception detected with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am developing an app that downloads an XML file, parses it and then displays the information on the screen.  I get a `NullPointerException` Exception error in the following code:

here is the code:

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<vehicleInfo>> {
    @Override
    protected List<vehicleInfo> doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            return getvehicles.processBusTime();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           return null;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<vehicleInfo> result) {


            for (int record = 0; record < result.size(); record++) {

            double latitude = result.get(record).latitude;
            double longitude = result.get(record).longitude;

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,     longitude)).title("Marker"));

        }

    }
}
```

it is returns a `NullPointerException` at the line:  `for (int record = 0; record < result.size(); record++) {`

what could be the issue?

thanks.

Comment: any of the 2 exceptions caught. you'd know if you logged them.

Answer (score 0):

`result` is `null`. Are you sure that `getvehicles.processBusTime()` is returning a list?

Comment: You are right. I think it is returning null.

Comment: Some jerk voted you down for being nice and answering a duplicate post with a correct answer!  I'm voting you back up.

Answer (score -1):

I would bet money that result is null.

if null is an acceptable value try something like:

```
 for (int record = 0; result != null && record < result.size(); record++)
```

Comment: I think getvehicles.processBusTime() is returning a null list object.